# How to count values including a particular word?

Tags: r, string, count

I have a vector with characters and would like to count values including a certain word.

For instance, I have this

```
vec1 = c("apple_a1","apple_a2","apple_a3"  ,"orange_a1","orange_a2" )
```

With `vec1`, How can I count values having "apple", and "orange" separately?

So, my desired outcome is 3 for apple and 2 for orange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sapply(c("apple", "orange"), function(x) sum(grepl(x, vec1)))
# apple orange 
#     3      2
```

Answer (score 2):

Or an option with `table` after removing the substring at the end

```
table(sub("_.*", "", vec1))
#  apple orange 
#    3      2
```

Comment: I guess another would be `table(sapply(strsplit(vec1,"_"), function(x) x[1]))`